# Inputting Incremental Database into Apache Storm Project

Tags: stream, teradata, apache-storm

I searched a lot but couldnt pretty much find what I was specifically looking for. The Question is simple and straightforward. 
I have a database table, which gets populated every second!
Next, I have almost defined the Analysis Methods/classes in the Apache Storm Spout/Bolts classes.
All I wish to do is, send those new rows being inserted every second to the Spout class as a stream input.
How Do I do this?

Thanks,

Comment: is its a must to get the data from the DB? getting data out as soon as it arrives from a DB requires constant pooling, If the frequency of update is so high (in sec as u mentioned) there could be alternate ways to make the job simpler

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could accomplish this, but without knowing more about the nature of the data it's hard to give a good answer. One way would be to use another table to track which records have already been processed by storm based on some field in the original table. For instance, if you used a timestamp column you could track the maximum timestamp you have already processed. There are some potential race conditions you have to be careful of with both the reading/updating of the metadata table as well as the actual data table, but both of those can be managed with transactions and proper time synchronization.

Comment: Logical. Ok lets make it simple. I want to access the whole table, all at once. Then?I could figure some solution out.as in using jdbc connection, and then select * isnt it?as in cursor reads one by one?isnt it?I cant program it right now else would have tested it right away!.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking me. Depending on the database you are using, you may or may not be able to continue to get new data with an open cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Teradata provide functionality of Queue tables. These tables support "select and consume" operation, which means it will remove rows from table as soon as you select them. For more information: http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1146_111A/ch01.032.045.html#ww798205
This approach assumes that table in Teradata is used as buffer and nobody else needs it. 
If you need to have both: permanent full table (for some other application) as well as streaming this data to Storm, you may want to modify your loading process in a way to populate permanent table as well as queue table. In this case other applications can use whole data depth in permanent table, and Storm will consume data from queue table with minimal space impact.